# (How) does C# know what type the object is?

Tags: c#, types, gettype, object-type

When `.GetType()` method is called upon an object, how does C# know its type? What if the object is identical to some other object type in the same project? Do they have some sort of unique identification (like GUID) baked into them?

Comment: `What if the object is identical to some other object type in the same project?` - That cannot happen. You cannot have 2 classes with the same name in the same namespace. That does not compile. Therefore classes can be uniquely identified.

Comment: Not the same name, but the same fields, properties and interfaces and whatnot.

Comment: This may be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296526/what-does-really-happen-when-you-do-gettype

Comment: Not the same name means it is a _different_ type.

Comment: Okay, but what if the name is the same, but the projects are different?

Comment: Then it is in a different assembly and is a different type.

Comment: @user1306322 The type name doesn't matter - it's the full *Type* of the object itself, which is always unique, since it inherently includes the assembly information.

Comment: Your second question is nonsensical; if you have *two* things that are *identical* to each other then you actually only have *one* thing. That's what *identical* means; it means the two things *have the same identity* and are therefore *the same thing*. "Identical twins" really should be called "similar twins"; they do not share an identity.

Comment: Well, I meant they have all the same things except their name. And that is code-wise, dunno about what happens when it is compiled.

Comment: @EricLippert The OP apparently didn't realize that all object instances stored information about their type, instead only storing them members, and thus he (incorrectly) assumed that two object instances with the same fields, even if they were from different classes, really would look identical.  How C# addresses that is by specifically storing information about what class each instance is with that object's data.  That's the "missing piece of the puzzle" for the OP, as it were.

Comment: That makes more sense; you *did* mean "identical" in the "twins" sense, which I misunderstood. What you're describing is called *structural typing*, where two types are considered to unify if they have the same internal structure. C# doesn't support structural typing except in a very limited way: anonymous types that have the same property names and types in the same order will unify within the same assembly, but not across assemblies. Structural typing would be particularly nice for delegate types; many people, myself included, wish that C# had been designed with structural delegate types.

Comment: I don't even know half of the terms, so yeah, I guess it's about what I was missing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When .GetType() method is called upon an object, how does C# know its type?

In addition to a memory location, the CLR actually stores type information with each and every object.

This is stored in the `TypeHandle`.  For details, see [Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx), in particular, the [Type Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S6) section.

When you call `Object.GetType()` on an object, the CLR does a lookup based on the TypeHandle in the object reference, and returns the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1):

> When .GetType() method is called upon an object, how does C# know its type?

Whenever a method is executed, the CLR creates a list of all types' static metadata refereed to inside the method, each with a reference to their Type object.

When an object is created (like using the `new` operator), the CLR adds a Type object pointer as it allocates the object in the heap, and directs this pointer to the static Type object, which contains information like the name of the type, the namespace, the list of methods and properties it defines, etc.

When `GetType` is called on the object it simply returns the reference its Type object points to, which is why even storing the instance into another variable of `object` type keeps a correct reference to its original type (the type it was created as).

> What if the object is identical to some other object type in the same project?

The type of an object is defined by its name, its namespace and its assembly. You cannot have two classes of the same name within the same namespace, as the compiler will complain of `Duplicate definition`. However, as long as they reside on different namespaces, `System.Foo.Bar` and `System.Bar` they can co-exists.