# How does GetType() knows the type of a derived class?

Tags: c#

Why this works:

```
Object o = "my string";
Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
```

Output:

```
System.String
```

This would make sense if the function call was dispatched to the `String` class, but it didn't since `GetType()` is not virtual.

Comment: Metadata. You don't get it with C# Native.

Comment: Try to use `ildasm.exe`

Comment: You may see: [What does really happen when you do GetType()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296526/what-does-really-happen-when-you-do-gettype)

Comment: Each object reference points to `ObjectInstance`, which has a `TypeHandle` embedded in it. There is a one-to-one correspondence between `System.Type` and `TypeHandle` within an app domain. [Here is an interesting article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7) if you would like to learn more about the internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution-time type is part of the data of the object itself. It's almost like it's a hidden read-only field in `System.Object`, and `GetType()` just returns the value of that field. (It's not quite that simple, but that's a reasonable approximation.)

Note that this information is necessary for the CLR to work out where to dispatch virtual methods - so if you were thinking it would work if `GetType` were virtual, ask yourself how the CLR would know which implementation to call.